# Liferay 6.2 User permissions

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I have created a 'Site User' role which is appropriate for users who will be Viewers on every available portlet. For example a user with this role should be only allowed to view documents in Documents and Media portlet but not allowed to add a new document or edit an existed.
I have defined the proper permissions in my Site role, however users with this Site role are still able to create events or add documents etc.

All these users are also assigned with the Social Office User role but as I'm seeing there is no such permission granted from this role.

I'm wondering if this is a normal behavior or the only solution is to modify portlets in a way that they won't allow users without the 'Site Admin' role to perform certain actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're assigned as default to Site Member role as Olaf stated. Look this file:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/resource-actions/documentlibrary.xml

As Site Member you have :

```
<site-member-defaults>
    <action-key>ADD_DOCUMENT</action-key>
    <action-key>ADD_FOLDER</action-key>
    <action-key>ADD_SHORTCUT</action-key>
    <action-key>SUBSCRIBE</action-key>
    <action-key>VIEW</action-key>
</site-member-defaults>
```

as default action permissions.

Answer (score 1):

They're most likely still assigned to the "User" role (portal wide), or gets the permission from being a "Site Member". As you can't remove permissions, only add them through roles, check these roles for their bundled permissions.

Comment: Hey Olaf, I've checked out that indeed these two roles(User, Site Member) are the additional roles from which a user can grant these 'add new doc' or 'add new calendar event' permissions. Checking through Liferay's UI for the bundled permissions of these two roles I found out that there is no such permission like add new Document type. However, Looking through DB table resourcepermission I found far more records than the bundled permissions of these roles in Liferay UI. Do you have any idea about this?